# Pyspark cumulative product using numpy

Tags: python, numpy, pyspark

I want to perform a cumulative product, previous successful answers use logarithmic sums to the the deed. However, is there a way to use Numpy cumsum. I have tried with no clear result, here is my code:

```
import numpy   as np

def cumulative_product (x):
    """Calculation of cumulative product using numpy function cumprod.
    """
    return np.cumprod(float(x)).tolist()

spark_cumulative_product = udf(cumulative_product, ArrayType(DoubleType()))

# the dataset in question:
param.show()
```

Which gives me for example:

```
+--------------+-----+
|financial_year|  wpi|
+--------------+-----+
|          2014|1.026|
|          2015|1.024|
|          2016|1.021|
|          2017|1.019|
|          2018|1.021|
+--------------+-----+
```

When applying

```
param = param.withColumn('cum_wpi', spark_cumulative_product(param_treasury['wpi']))
param.show()
```

I have that there are no changes i.e.

```
+--------------+-----+-------+
|financial_year|  wpi|cum_wpi|
+--------------+-----+-------+
|          2014|1.026|[1.026]|
|          2015|1.024|[1.024]|
|          2016|1.021|[1.021]|
|          2017|1.019|[1.019]|
|          2018|1.021|[1.021]|
+--------------+-----+-------+
```

Can anyone help on what is going wrong or if there is a better way to do cumprod without using exp-sum-log
-Update:
The desired output is:

```
+--------------+-----+-------+
|financial_year|  wpi|cum_wpi|
+--------------+-----+-------+
|          2014|1.026| 1.026 |
|          2015|1.024| 1.051 |
|          2016|1.021| 1.073 |
|          2017|1.019| 1.093 |
|          2018|1.021| 1.116 |
+--------------+-----+-------+
```

Comment: Do you want cumulative product ordered by financial year? If so, you need to do a groupby and pass in all the values in the Window. Right now you're only passing one value. What's the desired output? What version of spark? [In 2.4+, you can use `aggregate`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60300660/5858851).

Comment: Yes, the desired output is the cumulative product ordered by financial year, I have updated the question accordingly. Also the version I have is 2.4.4. I will have to take a look to aggregate; however, from the link provided, can it be done without creating a temporary column, in a one line.

Comment: **`transform`** will not work for your use case because it only accepts **`integer`** values while you have value with **3 decimal places**. i think your best bet is to use `cum_prod` with `pandas udf`

Comment: @MohammadMurtazaHashmi can't you use `aggregate` after a `collect_list`? It would be something like: `df.withColumn("cum_wpi", expr("aggregate(collect_list(wpi) over (order by financial_year), (acc, x) -> axx * x)")` - I don't see anywhere in the docs about only accepting integers (can you link me)? (I can't test right now.)

Comment: @pault i tried looking for links but it doesnt really say, i only found out after testing that aggregate function only accepts array of integer values. the output can be non integer but the input has to be integer. I tested on spark2.4.5 databricks cluster.

Comment: @pault update. so i was incorrect and I stand corrected. Aggregate can take doubles too and not only integers as long as the start acc has been cast as a double like this "aggregate(list,cast(0.5 as double),(acc,x)-> acc*x)", so apologies for my mistake.  i have updated answer with ur recommendation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way you can achieve this using **`cum_prod()`** pandas series function, using a **`pandas grouped map UDF`**.

**`Sample DataFrame:`**

```
#+--------------+-----+
#|financial_year|  wpi|
#+--------------+-----+
#|          2014|1.026|
#|          2015|1.024|
#|          2016|1.021|
#|          2017|1.019|
#|          2018|1.021|
#+--------------+-----+
```

I will first create a **dummy column**, which will be similar to our **`cum_wpi`**. I will overwrite this dummy column in the **`pandas udf`**. The use of **`orderBy`** right before the *groupby and apply* is there to **ensure** that the dataframe is sorted on **`financial_year`**.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.functions import pandas_udf, PandasUDFType
df1=df.withColumn("cum_wpi", F.lit(1.2456))
@pandas_udf(df1.schema, PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)
def grouped_map(df1):
     df1['cum_wpi']=df1['wpi'].cumprod().round(decimals=3)

     return df1
df.orderBy(F.col("financial_year").asc())\
  .groupby().apply(grouped_map).show()

#+--------------+-----+-------+
#|financial_year|  wpi|cum_wpi|
#+--------------+-----+-------+
#|          2014|1.026|  1.026|
#|          2015|1.024|  1.051|
#|          2016|1.021|  1.073|
#|          2017|1.019|  1.093|
#|          2018|1.021|  1.116|
#+--------------+-----+-------+
```

**`UPDATE:`**

You can use **`aggregate`** as mentioned earlier by @pault, as long as **`we cast acc(accumulator) to double`** we can handle your values.

```
df.withColumn("cum_wpi", F.expr("""format_number(aggregate(collect_list(wpi)\
                                    over (order by financial_year)\
                                    ,cast(1 as double),(acc,x)-> acc*x),3)"""))\
  .show(truncate=False)

#+--------------+-----+-------+
#|financial_year|wpi  |cum_wpi|
#+--------------+-----+-------+
#|2014          |1.026|1.026  |
#|2015          |1.024|1.051  |
#|2016          |1.021|1.073  |
#|2017          |1.019|1.093  |
#|2018          |1.021|1.116  |
#+--------------+-----+-------+
```

Comment: I understand your process; however, I was restraining to use pandas in the processing.  I have previously cleared all use of Pandas and Koalas to make it fast-running. I understand this is not the same but at the same time sounds like an over-kill. I am happy to accept your answer as there is no simpler solution.